# (firebase error) set failed first argument contains undefined in property

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

My add button gives me this error when I click it, but it still adds the input text to my firebase.

[image: error]

How do i get rid of this error?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
    import firebase from './firebase';
    export default class App extends Component {
    carDatabase = firebase.database().ref('car');

     state = { cars: {}, selectedId: '', text: ''}
     // Read


     componentDidMount() {
       this.carDatabase.on('value', cars => {
         const carsJSON = cars.val();

         this.setState({ cars: carsJSON === null ? {} : carsJSON  });
       })
       // this.carDatabase.push({color: 'yellow'})
     }
     // Create
     create() {
       this.carDatabase.push('space')  /// changes selected item
       this.setState({selectedId: ''})
     }

     add() {                                                          
      this.carDatabase.push(this.state.text).set(TextInput.value)   /// pushes textput to  firebase
      this.setState(TextInput.value)
    }


     // Update
     update() {
      this.carDatabase.child(this.state.selectedId).set('space')    /// changes text of selected item
      this.setState({selectedId: ''})
    }
     // Delete
     deleteCar() {
        if(this.state.selectedId === '') {           ///selects item
          return;

        }

       this.carDatabase.child(this.state.selectedId).set(null)          ///deletes item
      this.setState({selectedId: ''})
    }
        render() {
            return (


                <View style={styles.container}>
             <ScrollView>

             <Text style={styles.top}>Todo List</Text>

                <TextInput value={this.state.text} style={styles.textInput}></TextInput>

                 <Button title="create" onPress={() => this.create()}></Button> 
                 <Button title="update" onPress={() => this.update()}></Button> 
                 <Button title="delete" onPress={() => this.deleteCar()}></Button> 
                 <Button title="add" onPress={() => this.add()}></Button>


           {
           Object.keys(this.state.cars).map( (carId, index, text) =>
           <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedId: carId, text})}>
             <Text style={styles.input}>{`${JSON.stringify(this.state.cars[carId])}`} </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
             )
           }

           <TextInput                                          ///creates text input
              style={{height: 40}}
              placeholder="Type here to add"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}  
              value={this.state.text}                         ///gets text input
            />
            <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>   {this.state.text.value} </Text>  

    </ScrollView>

           {/* <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.cars, null, 2)}</Text> */}


         </View>
            );
        }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({




      container: {

        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        width: '100%'
    },


      textInput: {

       backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6',
       height: 40,
       width: '100%'

     },

     input: {

      backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6',
      padding: 20,
      marginVertical: 8,
      marginHorizontal: 16,
     },

     top: {

      backgroundColor: 'white',
      height: 45,
      paddingLeft: 140,
      paddingTop: 20,
      fontSize: 20,

      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'


     }


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

From the way you describe it, this is the call that is causing problems:

```
this.carDatabase.push(this.state.text).set(TextInput.value)
```

Since you say the database is still updated, it seems the `push(...)` works, but the `set(...)` is failing. As the error message says, that would be caused by `TextInput.value` being `undefined`.

If that is indeed the case, log the value of `TextInput.value` before you write it to the database and verify that it is what you expect it to be.

---

If the above is not the cause, then honesty it's too hard to determine exactly where the problem is coming from in what you've current shared. I'd recommend reducing the scope of your question and the code. Read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn why and how to do that, is it will drastically increase the chances that someone may help and will also often reduce the downvotes that your question attracts.